# Can I use iReport with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, jasper-reports

I really need to use iReport with AngularJS? Someone said it's not possible to use them both. Any recommend please?

Comment: The AngularJS is front end framework.
The JasperReports is working at server side with Java.
I think it's possible to use them both.

Comment: Oh really? okay, thanks for your answer! :D

Comment: What are you using with AngularJS? Using Node.js?
I've tested [node-jasper](https://github.com/agmoyano/node-jasper) and it worked although not perfect.
(node-jasper doesn't show Japanese character..)
Or call Java function from client-side or from node.js.

Comment: wow cool, I'll try it, thank you mate!